# Region between finite lines or extracting a finite tesselation

Tags: graphics, graphs-and-networks, regions, geometry, mesh

**EDIT2** the answers here ([How to compute intersections of circles on a lattice](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/165462/86543)) seem like they could help or solve the problem.

---

**EDIT:** I saw this [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/267189/86543) about finding regions between lines before I asked. The `ImageMesh` solution can work but there is some re-scaling involved because the scale is not conserved when moving from a graphics object to an image. Other solutions explicitly or implicitly rely on the existence of infinite lines. If it is safe to extend the lines to infinite lines then one can obtain the desired domain using :

```
RegionDifference[BoundingRegion@RegionUnion@lines, RegionUnion@ReplaceAll[Line->InfiniteLine]@lines]
```

That is **not** the case of the first example below as that would add extra squares by "completing" the figure within the bounding region.

That said if one is interested in the scenario where the shape is regular and it is safe to extend the lines within the bounding region then one can also use the cylindrical decomposition. It might be necessary to **rationalize** the equations before applying the decomposition (I did not and got an error). For example like this :

```
RegionDifference[BoundingRegion@RegionUnion@lines, 
    RegionUnion@ReplaceAll[Line -> InfiniteLine]@lines] // 
   Refine[RegionMember[#, {x, y}], Element[x | y, Reals]] & // 
  Rationalize[#, 0] &  // 
 CylindricalDecomposition[#, {x, y}, "Components"] &
```

Other solutions use `HalfSpace` this also relies on the existence of an infinite line.

The method using graphs in that question might work but I did not try long enough to understand it.

---

I would like the following input/output:

#### Input:

A list of geometric lines

Example 1:

```
ArrayMesh[{{1, 1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 0, 1}}] // 
MeshPrimitives[#, 1] &

{Line[{{1.,2.},{1.,3.}}],Line[{{1.,3.},{0.,3.}}],Line[{{0.,3.},{0.,2.}}],Line[{{0.,2.},{1.,2.}}],Line[{{2.,2.},{2.,3.}}],Line[{{2.,3.},{1.,3.}}],Line[{{1.,2.},{2.,2.}}],Line[{{4.,2.},{4.,3.}}],Line[{{4.,3.},{3.,3.}}],Line[{{3.,3.},{3.,2.}}],Line[{{3.,2.},{4.,2.}}],Line[{{1.,1.},{1.,2.}}],Line[{{0.,2.},{0.,1.}}],Line[{{0.,1.},{1.,1.}}],Line[{{2.,1.},{2.,2.}}],Line[{{1.,1.},{2.,1.}}],Line[{{3.,1.},{3.,2.}}],Line[{{3.,2.},{2.,2.}}],Line[{{2.,1.},{3.,1.}}],Line[{{4.,1.},{4.,2.}}],Line[{{3.,1.},{4.,1.}}],Line[{{2.,0.},{2.,1.}}],Line[{{1.,1.},{1.,0.}}],Line[{{1.,0.},{2.,0.}}],Line[{{4.,0.},{4.,1.}}],Line[{{3.,1.},{3.,0.}}],Line[{{3.,0.},{4.,0.}}]}
```

[image: lines]

Example 2

```
{Line[{{0., 92.2227}, {431.147, 750.}}], 
 Line[{{301.72, 750.}, {446.159, 0.}}], 
 Line[{{123.934, 750.}, {390.253, 0.}}], 
 Line[{{494., 432.03}, {0.470817, 750.}}], 
 Line[{{0., 388.081}, {494., 308.166}}]}
```

[image: lines2]

#### Output:

In simple words, I would like the squares/tiles in the image (see example below).

More precisely, I want a list of minimally sized regions whose union is equal to the union of lines of the input. I add minimally because in principle one might consider a subset of the union of squares/tiles.

The more precise request makes it a bit more difficult to understand but basically i would like to obtain the list of tiles that pave the image, the elements of the tessellation.

**Example:**

For the first input example above I would like the list:

```
ArrayMesh[{{1, 1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 0, 1}}] // 
MeshPrimitives[#, 2] &


(* {Polygon[{{1., 2.}, {1., 3.}, {0., 3.}, {0., 2.}}], Polygon[{{2., 
  2.}, {2., 3.}, {1., 3.}, {1., 2.}}], Polygon[{{4., 2.}, {4., 3.}, {
  3., 3.}, {3., 2.}}], Polygon[{{1., 1.}, {1., 2.}, {0., 2.}, {0., 
  1.}}], Polygon[{{2., 1.}, {2., 2.}, {1., 2.}, {1., 1.}}], Polygon[{{
  3., 1.}, {3., 2.}, {2., 2.}, {2., 1.}}], Polygon[{{4., 1.}, {4., 
  2.}, {3., 2.}, {3., 1.}}], Polygon[{{2., 0.}, {2., 1.}, {1., 1.}, {
  1., 0.}}], Polygon[{{4., 0.}, {4., 1.}, {3., 1.}, {3., 0.}}]} *)
```

Visualization (each color roughly represents a polygon in the list above):

[image: vis]

#### Optimal solution for me

A solution that only uses geometry and graphics. In particular I want to avoid solutions that convert the graphics object to an image because I am unable to get Mathematica to use the right image size while preserving resolution.

#### Possible solutions

**Geometric solution**

One could maybe add a point very close to each line to turn the line to a triangle and then use `RegionDifference` of the `RegionUnion` of the modified lines (that are now triangles) with the `BoundaryRegion` of the `RegionUnion` of the lines (basically getting the complement region).

This solution is a bit ugly I do not really like it and have not tried it yet

**Image solution**

One could use `ComponentMeasurements` or `// ImageMesh // ConnectedMeshComponents` but this has the issue that it converts the graphics object to an image which changes the scale and then the scale of the rectangles are not the same as the original rectangles

**Graph solution**

One could convert the lines to points and lines using  `// Apply[RegionUnion] // DiscretizeRegion` and then to a graph to search for cycles. I do not know how to do this at the moment but I might consider searching for ways to do that

Comment: Are the tiles always going to have 4 sides? In that case: ``Polygon /@ 
 FindCycle[Graph[First /@ Apply[UndirectedEdge, lines, {2}]], {4}, 
   All][[All, All, 1]]`` where ``lines`` is your list of lines.

Comment: @Domen Nice (: . I told myself converting the lines to a graph would be complicated but it is a one liner. The example I gave was bad. In general the end points of the lines are not the the intersection with other lines but your solution worked by adding a bit more functions. Thank you.

Comment: The solution in the general case with random lines can be converted to the case you looked at with `RegionUnion` which adds the intersections. The full solution is then:  `lines // Apply[RegionUnion] // MeshPrimitives[#, 1] & // 
      ReplaceAll[Line -> Identity] // MapApply[UndirectedEdge] // FindCycle[#, {4}, All] & // 
  ReplaceAll[UndirectedEdge -> List] // Map[CrossingPolygon]`

Comment: Many complicated things in Mathematica can be converted to funky one-liners :) I suggest you post your solution as a proper answer.

Comment: I will add another example to make the generality of the question clearer. You can add your solution if you would like to.

Comment: it's your solution (:

Comment: @Domen that said, I am curious about the general case where polygons vary in shape. In that case the lengths of the minimal cycles would vary. Do you have an idea for that case ? Maybe `FindShortestPath`

Comment: In that case, perhaps [`PlanarFaceList`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlanarFaceList.html) is more suitable (introduced in V13), or [`IGFaces`](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGDocumentation/#igfaces) from package [IGraph/M](http://szhorvat.net/pelican/igraphm-a-mathematica-interface-for-igraph.html). The former, however, seems to sometimes also return some spurious faces; I haven't tested the latter.

Comment: @Domen niiiiiice. Dang that is convenient. I asked right in time.

Comment: I can include your answers in my question or in an answer (referencing to you) if you rather not write an answer. I just do not want to steal an answer from you if you want to answer.

Comment: @Domen I referenced your answers at the top of the question

Comment: related https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/267189/divide-a-geometric-region-by-many-lines/

Comment: @cvgmt hello I saw that one and spent lots of time trying the methods but either they did not work, they seemed unrelated or they were too long and lengthy to understand. I will include that link to my question however thank you.

Comment: @Domen I checked and PlanarFaceList weirdly includes edges that point out of a face as part of the face. Other than that it did not work as it did not provide minimal polygons in the original image. I will just stick to the `FindCycle` and maybe consider the geometric one in my question that makes triangles from lines.

Comment: @cvgmt I saw that the answer with the different methods is yours. That is the answer I tried to follow. The polygon decomposition did not create rectangles when the lines formed a grid. The image mesh solution works but it rescales all the objects as it converts the graphics object to an image. The region symmetric difference method starts with rectangles and points I do not understand how it answered the question about lines. I did not understand how the animation method finds the region between lines for lines that were determined before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure if your problem is fully defined, but here's one approach to start with, discretizing boundaries of finite components and showing them. `CylindricalDecomposition` is not limited to supporting only infinite lines, when it is provided with suitable exact definitions line segments are fine too.

```
With[{lines = 
       ArrayMesh[{{1, 1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 0, 1}}] // 
        MeshPrimitives[#, 1] &},
     RegionDifference[FullRegion[2], 
        RegionUnion[Rationalize[lines, 0]]] // 
       Refine[RegionMember[#, {x, y}], Element[x | y, Reals]] & // 
      CylindricalDecomposition[#, {x, y}, "Components"] &] // 
    Map[ImplicitRegion[#, {x, y}] &] // Select[BoundedRegionQ] // 
  Map[Quiet@*BoundaryDiscretizeRegion] // Show
```

[image]

```
With[{lines = {Line[{{0., 92.2227}, {431.147, 750.}}], 
        Line[{{301.72, 750.}, {446.159, 0.}}], 
        Line[{{123.934, 750.}, {390.253, 0.}}], 
        Line[{{494., 432.03}, {0.470817, 750.}}], 
        Line[{{0., 388.081}, {494., 308.166}}]}},
     RegionDifference[FullRegion[2], 
        RegionUnion[Rationalize[lines, 0]]] // 
       Refine[RegionMember[#, {x, y}], Element[x | y, Reals]] & // 
      CylindricalDecomposition[#, {x, y}, "Components"] &] // 
    Map[ImplicitRegion[#, {x, y}] &] // Select[BoundedRegionQ] // 
  Map[Quiet@*BoundaryDiscretizeRegion] // Show
```

[image]

You can also replace `FullRegion[2]` with `Quiet@BoundingRegion[RegionUnion[Rationalize[lines, 0]]]` in the latter case (`Quiet` is for surpressing a strange, spurious error message) for getting tiles which would otherwise seem to be part of the unbounded exterior:

[image]

One might ask why this implicit bounding rectangle would be assumed. One could also consider, for instance, in this case a convex hull (like `ConvexHullRegion[Join @@ Rationalize[lines[[All, 1]], 0]]`):

[image]

Comment: Very nice. `FullRegion` here was a very neat idea and I am not even sure I knew about it. The complement with the bounding region or convex hull's introduce extra tiles that I did not want which was the problem I had with implementing your answer from the linked post when transforming the lines to infinite lines and taking the region difference with the bounding region as in the edit 1 code.

Comment: I also did not know that rationalizing the lines before with `RegionUnion` and `RegionDifference` leads to different behavior. Thank you for this  answer that provides a lot of interesting information for future use. I will wait a day before I accept an answer.

Comment: I recently read about `RegionConvert` and tried replacing the `RegionMember` part of your code with `RegionConvert[#, "Implicit"] & // Apply[Reduce[##, Reals] &]` and it was 10 times faster.  I don't know if you already tried that so I mentioned it.

Comment: @userrandrand I've tried it, but I didn't benchmark it...

Answer (score 1):

This is not a complete answer but in case no answer comes here is a partial solution for the case where the lines form a grid of squares:

```
lines // Apply[RegionUnion] // MeshPrimitives[#, 1] & // 
 ReplaceAll[Line -> Identity] // MapApply[UndirectedEdge] // 
 FindCycle[#, {4}, All] & // ReplaceAll[UndirectedEdge -> List] // 
 Map[CrossingPolygon]
```

Perhaps that would also work for a triangular lattice and other regular lattices but it is insufficient for a random lattice as the number of vertices vary. One could consider turning the lines to a graph and obtaining the faces of the graph using [PlanarFaceList](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlanarFaceList.html) (version 13) but the polygons obtained were not the minimal (smallest) ones. Maybe using `FindShortestPath` would work using the same beginning and end vertex but that might be lengthy to apply for each vertex.